# What do the voltage and current labels on a relay signify?

Tags: relay

The relay is just a switch. What do the  labels       for the maximum amount of current and voltage it can handle mean?

As an example, see this

https://www.industrybuying.com/relays-relay-EL.SW.RE.374881/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PLA&utm_campaign=0_PLA_LPP&gclid=CIGVkaSOkckCFQKTjgod7TgNQQ

The relay on this page, has written on it. 5A 240V, what does this mean?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you about those numbers?

Comment: electrical device just can't operate upto infinite voltage/current..all has their own upper limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the maximum voltage and current on the switch (=load contacts) side. The current is for a resistive load. You also need to worry about the coil side parameters.

Also you should consider buying stuff where photo and web page agree. The latter says 12V, although looking at the very fuzzy picture they have, that seems to be coil voltage. Never mind that there noting resembling a datasheet for that relay. You get what you pay for.

A [guide like this](http://www.hongfa.com/pdf/EXPLANATION%20TO%20TERMINOLOGY%20AND%20GUIDELINES%5CExplanation%20to%20terminology%20and%20guidelines_General%20relay_en.pdf) or [this (which is more detailed)](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/pew/hu/downloads/ds_x61_en_relay_technical_information.pdf) is worth reading before buying relays.

Comment: the fuzzy image say also says 10A 125VAC and 10A 25VDC